# Unable to start new activity from ExpandableListView OnChildClickListener

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am having a strange problem. I am unable to start a new activity from ExpandableListView OnChildClickListener. I can set and view the toast, but when I add intent the app stopped working.

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " : " + listDataChild.get(
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition) +" gp "
                        + String.valueOf(groupPosition) +" cp "+String.valueOf(childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        /*Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), VerseActivity.class);
        //intent.putExtra("verse_name", groupPosition);
        //intent.putExtra("chapter_number",childPosition);
        startActivity(intent);*/

        return false;
    }
});
```

Please help me solve this problem. I am using fragments.

Answer (score 1):

try with the below thing. You need to `return true` in the `onChildClick` method.

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " : " + listDataChild.get(
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition) +" gp "
                        + String.valueOf(groupPosition) +" cp "+String.valueOf(childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), VerseActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("verse_name", groupPosition);
        intent.putExtra("chapter_number",childPosition);
        startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you got a chance to look into this?

Comment: Yes, but it does not work. I have modified the whole code. I have used a TextView to show the content on the same fragment, and added a cross button.